# Python socket recv taking ages to deliver packet

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, delay

I have a Python 3 program which sends short commands to a host and gets short responses back (both 20 bytes). It's not doing anything complicated.

The socket is opened like this:

```
  self.conn = socket.create_connection( ( self.host, self.port ) )
  self.conn.settimeout( POLL_TIME )
```

and used like this:

```
  while( True ):
    buf = self.conn.recv( 256 )
    # append buffer to bigger buffer, parse packet once we've got enough bytes
```

After my program has been running for a while (hours, usually), sometimes it goes into a strange mode - if I use tcpdump, I can see a response packet arriving at the local machine, but recv doesn't give me the packet until 30s (Windows) to 1m (Linux) later. The time is random +/- about ten seconds. I wondered if the packet was being delayed til the next packet arrived, but this doesn't seem to be true.

In the meantime, the same program is also operating a second socket connection using the same code on a different thread, which continues to work normally.

This doesn't happen all the time, but it's happened several times in a month. Sometimes it's preceded by a few seconds of packets taking longer and longer to arrive, but most of the time it just goes straight from OK to completely broken. Most of the time it stays broken for hours until I restart the server, but last night I noticed it recovering and going back to normal operation, so it's not irrecoverable.

CPU usage is almost zero, and nothing else is running on the same machine.

The weirdest thing is that this happens on both the Linux Subsystem for Windows (two different laptops), and on Linux (AWS tiny instance running Amazon Linux).

I had a look at the CPython implementation of socket.recv() using GDB. Looking at the source code, it looks like it passes calls to socket.recv() straight through to the underlying recv(). However, while the outer function sock_recv() (which implements socket.recv() ) gets called frequently, it only calls recv() when there's actually data to read from the socket, using the socket_call() function to call poll()/select() to see if there's any data waiting. Calls to recv() happen directly before the app receives a packet, so the delay is somewhere before that point, rather than between recv() and my code.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

(Both the Linux and Windows machines are updated to the most recent everything, and the Python is Python 3.6.2)

[edit] The issue gets even weirder. I got fed up and wrote a method to detect the issue (looking for ten late-arriving packets in a row with near-identical roundtrip times), drop the connection and reconnect (by closing the previous connection and creating a new socket object) ... *and it didn't work.* Even with a new socket object, the delayed packets remain delayed by exactly the same amount. So I altered the method to completely kill the thread that was running that code and restart it, reasoning that perhaps there was some thread-local state. *That still didn't work.* The only resort I have left is killing the entire program and having a watchdog to restart it...

[edit2] Killing the entire program and restarting it with an external watchdog worked. It's a terrible solution, but at least it's a solution.

Comment: The reason is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289981/python-sockets-stop-recv-from-hanging

Comment: Axalix: the socket already has a timeout set (100ms). The packet is being delivered an entire minute late, after several socket.recv() calls returned nothing.

Comment: Can you produce an http://sscce.org/ ?

Comment: @AndyWalker having just a timeout is not enough. The link I posted in my first comment is not about timeouts.

Comment: Can you reproduce the fault by unplugging the Ethernet wire from your computer for 30 seconds, and then plugging it back in?  (my suspicion is that you may be seeing TCP respond to a temporary network outage by dialing back the resend-rate and the window size to extremely small values)

Comment: @Axalix - the link you posted was about a socket *blocking* for ages. This is not the issue I'm having at all.

Comment: I might be able to reproduce the issue on my stress-tester setup, either by running for a while or by unplugging a cable. I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: I set up a local server and this Python client, got it going, and unplugged the cable for 30s. Unlike in the issue above, my code got an error that indicated the connection had dropped, reconnected, and resumed working normally. So it doesn't look like a straightforward connection issue causing TCP to do weird things.